# WebDriver Java Collections types with scenarios

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, collections

Can anyone explain some real time application/framework scenarios in Selenium where different types of collections are used? And why you selected that type(ArrayList, Set and Map)? Wanted to specifically know why other types are not useful in those scenarios.

Thanks,
Dennis

Comment: Can you let us know your exact requirement?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a general idea:

1) ArrayLists can be used to store webElements' values.

2) I've used SET for storing various window handles.

3) Map is used while fetching no of (Key, value pairs) values from Excel sheets.